# npm ionic install error in node.js

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

I'm quite upset by the day. Give me best solution.

Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.38 (x64) and npm.

```
C:\Users\ASAR-KSS>npm install -g ionic
npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
    npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\ASAR-KSS
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.38
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ASAR-KSS\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

C:\Users\ASAR-KSS>
```

Comment: try with 'sudo npm install -g ionic'

Comment: following err :
C:\Users\ASAR-KSS>sudo npm install -g ionic
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: sudo applicable only linux machine

Comment: my OS= Windows 7 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Update npm to the [latest version](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node). Try again. Seems that it can't find the package, or you're using an outdated npm version.

If that doesn't work, check whether you're sitting behind a proxy or make sure you've not configured a proxy in the `~/.npmrc` file.

The error `network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` suggests that the http address for the package cannot be found or is being altered because you're sitting behind a proxy.

Comment: how to setup a proxy ? i am newcomer in node.js and ionic framework

Comment: @RasheeqUsmani Here's an indepth guide that will be more useful then I will! https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy

Comment: Thanks Buddy .. I see

Answer (score 0):

if you want to install ionic 1, use nodejs 4.4.4 instead of node 6 or 7. After installation execute the folowing command line:

```
npm install -g cordova ionic@1.7.14
```

I try it and it resolve my problem